# Question on initial sync and Freezer (SSD and HDD)

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, state-trie

I've kicked off a fresh fast sync of Geth v1.9.2 and  after 3 weeks it's still pulling states (state trie).

As per the documentation you can use the Freezer with a HDD as it references old data so my setup is 1 x SSD (7500 IOPS) for the main chain and 1 x HDD (500 IOPS) for the freezer.

My question is during the initial sync should I move the Freezer data to the SSD and then move it back to the HDD? The reasoning is that syncing is just taking so long compared to v1.8.x which took only 4-5 days to complete with the same hardware and im concerned this may be an issue.

Appreciate any input on this.